# Floating and Clearing... Why cant I mix/match float:left/right + margin: 0 auto for perfect alignment of 3 elements?

Tags: html, css

So, I guess I'm just having trouble really fundamentally understanding what's happening here and I would like an in-depth explanation so I can finally grasp what seems to be mysterious behavior.

I have 3 block elements, all with fixed widths and heights, and I'd like one to be aligned to the left side of the screen, one directly in the center, and one on the right side of the screen.  In my head, I feel as though I should be able to do something like this:

CSS

```
div {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: black;
    clear: none;
}

#a {
    float: left;
}

#b {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#c {
    float: right;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
<div id="c"></div>
```

But it unfortunately doesn't work.  In the above configuration, the third element "c" is on the right side of the page but it's been cleared to the next line.  Would really just like to understand why.

Here's a fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m2V36/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b` is taking all the available margin on the right, then there's no space available for `c`.

```
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="c"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
```

Just does the expected behavior, so in short, first define your floats (left, right) then the middle part.

Another solution is to make div's act like table cells, (`display:table-cell`) then you will need a parent div with `display:table`:

Example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m2V36/2/)

Note: This will make a layout of 3 filled columns, I don't know if this is what you want or you really want these boxes separate.

Comment: I see... So I guess the thing to remember with floated elements is that they're always subject to margin constraints.  I get it now.  Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't work that way. Think in the order that they come into place and the fact that margin is taking the defined space. Box model reference: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Comment: Right, exactly.  So when you put the floated elements first in order, there are no margin constraints for them to obey so they float on the same line without a problem.  Then, when you add the `margin:0 auto` element afterward, that "auto calculation" now fills up the remaining space on the line.  So, when you're floating elements, it's important to keep in mind that they fall victim to spacing issues that are affected by margins.  That's all I was getting at.